# Yes/No Window display scrambled. What are the cause?

Tags: memory, vb6, window, graphic

There is a vb6 built desktop application EXE running in Windows environment. Sometimes, when the prompt window loads it is all scrambled. When I minimize the window and then re-open, it is fixed. Any idea what could be the root cause?
[image]

Is this a code issue? Memory issue? Graphic Card?

Comment: Wow, that's unique. Is this a VB form or a dialog created by calling MsgBox() ?

Comment: Can you share the code that calls up this window?

Comment: Its a simple msgbox() and by simple I mean there is no variable passed to it. Everything hard coded.

Comment: Have you tried running it on another pc?

Comment: Happens only on one machine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I suspect is to do with the property of the command window on that particular machine. 
Open cmd.exe, click on the icon, go to the property, go to the layout tab and check if it has got enough buffer size. Try to match with the machine on with its working.